# React Functional HOC with Generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-functions

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I think my issue is different. I am not looking to learn how to implement a `HOC`, I have already done that (although not yet test :)), my problem is using it.

Below is my HOC

```
const withBaseFunctionality =
<T extends BaseModel, P extends BaseProps<T>>(
WrappedComponent: FunctionComponent<P>
) =>
(props: P) => {
//States
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

//Update props
const updatedProps = produce(props, (draftProps) => {
  draftProps.handlePageChange = handlePageChange;
  draftProps.fetchItems = fetchItems;
  draftProps.handleCreateItem = handleCreateItem;
  draftProps.handleUpdateItem = handleUpdateItem;
  draftProps.handleDeleteItem = handleDeleteItem;
});

//API
const fetchItems = useItems(props.subPath, page - 1);
//Handles all the create logic
const handleCreateItem = (item: T) => {};

//Handles all the update logic
const handleUpdateItem = (item: T) => {};

//Handles all the delete logic
const handleDeleteItem = (item: T) => {};

//Handles page changes
const handlePageChange = (page: number) => setPage(page);

return <WrappedComponent {...updatedProps} />;
};
```

export default withBaseFunctionality;

and how I am trying to use it

```
interface TestModel extends BaseModel{
name: string;
acronym: string;   
}


interface TestProps extends BaseProps<TestModel>{


}


const TestPage: FunctionComponent<TestProps>  = ({}) => {


return<></>;

}

export default withBaseFunctionality(TestPage);
```

I am getting the error below on this line `export default withBaseFunctionality(TestPage);`

```
Argument of type 'FunctionComponent<TestProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'FunctionComponent<BaseProps<BaseModel>>'.
Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
Type 'WeakValidationMap<TestProps> | undefined' is not assignable to type 
'WeakValidationMap<BaseProps<BaseModel>> | undefined'.
  Type 'WeakValidationMap<TestProps>' is not assignable to type 
'WeakValidationMap<BaseProps<BaseModel>>'.
    Types of property 'handleCreateItem' are incompatible.
      Type 'Validator<(item: TestModel) => void> | undefined' is not assignable to type 
'Validator<(item: BaseModel) => void> | undefined'.
        Type 'Validator<(item: TestModel) => void>' is not assignable to type 
'Validator<(item: BaseModel) => void>'.
          Type '(item: TestModel) => void' is not assignable to type '(item: BaseModel) => 
 void'.ts(2345)
```

Please note that I am not very good at `Typescript or JS`, I am using my `Java` knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking the application, all I needed to do is create TestPage like this
`const TestPage = ({fetchItems}: TestProps) => {` and all the errors are gone, in fact, even the logic in the `HOC` works.